# How to use dplyr to modify a column of factors?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
library(magrittr)
x <- structure(
  list(col1 = structure(
    c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L),
    .Label = c("C",
               "Q", "S"),
    class = "factor"
  )),
  .Names = "col1",
  row.names = c(NA, -5L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame")
)
```

I would like to replace all rows with value 'S' in col1 with 'C'.

This works as expected:

```
x[x$col1 == 'S',] <- 'C'
```

I tried to do the replacement with dplyr using the following code:

```
x %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col1 = ifelse(col1 == 'S', 'C', col1))
```

But it instead gave a column of integers where each integer represents the corresponding level for how the factor variable i.e. col1 was coded:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 1]

   col1
  (int)
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     1
5     1
```

Why did dplyr do this and what is the proper way to do the replacement using dplyr?

Output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lazyeval_0.2.0 R6_2.1.2       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.3.2 DBI_0.3.1      tools_3.3.2   
[7] dplyr_0.4.3    Rcpp_0.12.7
```

Comment: The issue is with `ifelse` and it's interaction with `factor`s, not `dplyr` - `ifelse(x$col1 == 'S', 'C', x$col1)` for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `library(forcats)` and `fct_recode()` to adjust your factor like this:

```
library(forcats)
y <- x %>% dplyr::mutate(col1 = fct_recode(col1, "C" = "S"))

levels(x$col1) # original
[1] "C" "Q" "S"
levels(y$col1) # new
[1] "C" "Q"
```

`fct_recode` works a lot like `dplyr::rename` just with character strings instead of bare colnames. Unmentioned levels are left unchanged.

Comment: What if instead of replacing a factor's level, I need to identify a row with a missing value for that factor and replace it with some level? I can't think of  a way to avoid using `ifelse()` in this situation.

Comment: my initial thought would be use `is.na` with a `gsub`. `?dplyr::case_when` might be worth a look too. If you edit in an example or ask another question, I am happy to try and help :) Feel free to chat me too

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning `dplyr::case_when`. I was able to solve that problem using this function.